# find out the count of current element within its parent using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</a>
```

I want to find out the count of the current element that i am parsing 
when my node is in that current element and i am not aware the element names as well.

I tried :

```
<xsl:for-each select="a">
   <counter localName="{local-name()}" count="{count(node()/*)}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output I expect:

```
 <counter localName="b" count="2"/>
 <counter localName="b" count="2"/>
 <counter localName="c" count="1"/>
```

this gives a wrong output how do i achieve it ?

Comment: Please add a sample of what you would like to obtain -- and select xslt either xslt-1.0 or xslt-2.0, not both. Thanks.

Comment: i have eddited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do:

```
<xsl:template match="/a">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <counter localName="{local-name()}" count="{count(../*[local-name()=local-name(current())])}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

This will return:

```
<root>
  <counter localName="b" count="2"/>
  <counter localName="b" count="2"/>
  <counter localName="c" count="1"/>
</root>
```

---

Do note that by using `local-name()` you are purposefully ignoring the namespace. Thus the result will be the same if the input happens to be:

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <ns1:b xmlns:b="http://example.com/b"/>
  <c/>
</a>
```

although clearly the two `b` nodes counted together have nothing in common except by coincidence.